# Cors - This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a node backend, which should allow cross origin request from my frontend application that is running on localhost:3000. Therefore I've restricted the cors policy to my domain.

```
import csrf from 'csurf';

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
  })
);

const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 900,
    domain: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
})

router.get('/csrfToken', csrfProtection, async (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ token: req.csrfToken() });
});
```

When I'm making now a request to my server endpoint (which is running on localhost:5000), it returns me the following error that the cookie cannot be set.

```
  fetch('http://localhost:5000/csrfToken', {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include'
 })
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: And what does that Set-Cookie header look like? All the picture shows is that it starts with `http:/` which isn't helpful.

Comment: And where is your server-side code which outputs that header? You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with CORS.

Comment: @Quentin Okay thanks, I've updated now the question. The configuration seems to be okay, but i have a suspicion that set-cookies doesn't work on localhost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has nothing to do with CORS. It is just how cookies work.

---

The domain in the `set-cookie` header says `http://localhost:3000` but the request is for `http://localhost:5000`.

That is a different origin and so is an invalid cookie.

---

It is impossible for a `set-cookie` header from one origin to set a cookie for a different origin. `http://localhost:5000` can only set cookies for `http://localhost:5000`.

---

If you really want to set a cookie for `:3000` then a work-around would be to provide the data through some other format than a cookie (e.g. in the request body) and then have the client-side JS on `http://localhost:3000` set the cookie using [the document.cookie API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

If you want to set the cookie for `:5000` (which seems more likely), then get the port number right in the `set-cookie` header.

```
const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 900,
    domain: 'http://localhost:5000'
  }
})
```

Comment: I've to set the cookie for :3000.

The reason is that I'm using the module csurf (https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf), which says that the token (and the cookie) should be sent from the server (:5000) to my client app(:3000).

So when the client is making a request back to server, it should send it along the previously received token and cookie to authenticate the request.

That means it's not possible for me to store the cookie from the server when I'm running the client app on a different domain?

Comment: @ProV — If you want the client to send the token back to the server running on `:5000` then you need to set the cookie for `:5000`. If you set the cookie for `:3000` then it will only be included in requests for port `:3000`!

Comment: So when I'm set the domain option from the module csrf to localhost:5000, like you mentioned above, it's still gives me same error.

Comment: @ProV — Try leaving `domain` out and trusting to the defaults.

Comment: Oh thank you, another thing that i learned about cookies :)
Leaving out the domain works.

Comment: @ProV which domain reference did you leave out to get it to work? I'm having the same problem. Can you post here the code line that contained the domain so I can try the same? Thx.

Comment: @Ric Just don't use a specific domain at all. On the example above i removed the line `domain: 'http://localhost:5000'` and it worked.

Comment: The domain name without protocol and port number will also work. Like `domain:'localhost'`

Answer (score 2):

i met this problem today too. i used chrome browser which version higher than 80.
chrome add a new attribute "samesite" to defend csrf which from v51.
chrome v80+ default limit cross-site set cookie, make cookie invalid.
**console warning**：
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute.
It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

chrome://flags/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmvR1.png)

Comment: search samesite, and set these disabled.

Comment: So were you able to solve this yourself? If disabling them is sufficient for you, then add this as Answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone lands here from Laravel (sanctum), can try this for their local servers:-

```
//.env file. Try removing :port from SESSION_DOMAIN
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="127.0.0.1:8000"
SESSION_DOMAIN="127.0.0.1"
```

Comment: You may need to add `127.0.0.1:3000` or any port that your frontend is running on for `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`. 


`SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS:"127.0.0.1:8000,127.0.0.1:3000`