# this set-cookie was blocked because its domain with docker and nginx

Tags: docker, vue.js, symfony, nginx, cookies

first time using docker and nginx reverse proxy.

**Setup**

- Dockerized front with Vuejs behind localhost:4200
- Dockerized back with Symfony behind a dockerized nginx on localhost:80

**Trouble**

Every time I add a cookie to the response, the Set-Cookie get ignored by the front.
[image]

Telling me:

```
This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url.
```

**What I tried**

- Add different domain to the cookie config.
- Add a new header within nginx.

As I said, I m new with this setup, can't figure if the problem come from nginx or the cookie config.

*Edit: It actually work fine with postman.*

Comment: Does this resolve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60953427/cors-this-set-cookie-domain-attribute-was-invalid-with-regards-to-the-current

Comment: Thank for you answer but actually not, I tried to set the domain of the cookie to : http://127.0.0.1:80 (which is nginx) and still return the error.
I also tried with the direct link to my backend container but still not working.

Comment: Are you connecting to nginx by navigating to `127.0.0.1:80` or just `127.0.0.1` ? The URL must match the cookie domain, including port specified. Despite both those URLs connecting to port 80, if you're not defining it but the cookie specifies it then they don't match

Comment: I use 127.0.0.1 to request the backend and set the domain to 127.0.0.1 ( actually i tried both with 127.0.0.1:80) and still not working.
I juste edited the post but its actually work fine with postman.