# Add cookie do all subdomains of a domain with express

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, cookies

I want to make a login request to `api.localhost:3000` to login a user and save a cookie. This cookie should be accessible from all the subdomains of `localhost`.

```
res.cookie("smjwt", token, { expires: 1, sameSite: "none", secure: true, domain: "localhost" })
res.cookie("smjwt", token, { expires: 1, sameSite: "none", secure: true, domain: ".localhost" })
res.cookie("smjwt", token, { expires: 1, sameSite: "none", secure: true, domain: "*.localhost" })
```

The methods above don't work. I can only set the cookie if domain is `api.localhost` or is empty, and it is only accessible on `api` subdomain.
The error is

> This attempt to set cookie via Set-Cookie header was blocked because its Domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url

I want the cookie to be set to all the subdomains, so user is logged in everywhere and doesn't have to always login when on different subdomain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60953789/2073738

Comment: no, i set the domain to `https://localhost:3000` and still have the same issue